# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to give permissions to my AWS bucket to be able to upload files. I have tried updating the public access to public, and changing my bucket policy. I am sort of stuck and I am not sure how to proceed this issue.

Bucket Policy:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::id:user1"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::id:user2"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Update: I am able to upload a file using the python command console, but not in my source code. Here is what I have

```
s3.boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('file.csv', 'bucket', 'file.csv')
```

I have also tried:

```
s3.boto.resource('s3')
s3.Object('bucket').upload_fileobj(object)
```

Comment: You are trying your source code from the same place that are you executing your python commands?

Comment: Yes, I am using Flask as the framework. Using the virualenv and without it works in the command line

Comment: Is in an EC2 instance? Check if you have IAM Role assigned to the instance that allow full access to S3

Comment: Where are you running this code from?

Comment: @conde this is an s3 instance.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad we have a liquid web Centos 7 server where python 3.6.8 is installed. We initiate the s3 instance with the AWS environment keys the same way from the app and the console command

Comment: And where did you run your python command console from? The same server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To successfully connect with AWS I had to pass credentials to the s3 resource

`s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='key', aws_secret_access_key='key')`